# Treatment of space in quotation marks in listings

Tags: listings, typography

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=sh]
command "A B"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

the output is:

[image]

The replacement of the space with a visible character is not appealing.  The problem is solved by removing `[language=sh]`. However, how to patch it for `[language=sh]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=sh,showstringspaces=false]
command "A B"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]